# New item activated in Conductor does not show it

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, contentcontrol

I'm activating new item in conductor using Caliburn.Micro.Contrib's [ConductResult](https://github.com/kmees/CMContrib/blob/master/src/CMContrib.SL/Results/ConductResult.cs). Conductor is of type `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`, and there is already one item showing and working correctly.

The new item however is not shown after it was activated. I already checked and the conductor's **ActiveItem** is set to that new item, new item **is activated** as well. View's **IsVisible** of new item is also set to true, so I don't understand why it is not visible.

XAML of the conductor's view is pretty simple:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=ActiveItem, Converter={StaticResource objectTypeConverter}}" Margin="5" />
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="10 ">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource objectTypeConverter},ConverterParameter=something}" Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ActiveItem" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

(TextBlock and ItemsControl are there for debugging purposes; they prove that new item is conducted within conductor (i.e. Items collection contains it) and new item is set as ActiveItem)

Comment: Have you managed to fix this, because I have (about) the same problem.

Comment: As far as I remember, cause of these type of problems (newly activated item in Conductor is not shown) was usually that Conductor itself was not activated (or its parent Conductor). So, I suggest that you take a look, if all parent items/conductors are properly activated.

Comment: They are, because adding new items to the right works fine. It's just adding items to the left that doesn't work. I'm asking a similar question here with full example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835842/pivotitem-isnt-properly-activated-by-conductor-in-caliburn-micro

Comment: Well, then unfortunately I don't know what could cause this problem. I've fixed my problem and haven't experienced any issues with Caliburn.Micro's conductors/screens later.

Comment: Can you share some code over email? Mine's dvdstelt at outlook.com. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `IoC.Get<IShell>` to access the parent viewmodel.

The default bootstrapper says `container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();`
That’s why I was getting another instance of my `ShellViewModel` class, activated the item just fine, but no UI was updating.

One way to fix is replace `container.PerRequest` with `container.Singleton`.
Another is change `IoC.Get<IShell>()` into `( (IShell)Parent )`